# Dynamic resizing linear layout depending on location in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-studio

Im using android studio to develop an app, I want to have a table with a list of options that changes depending on location, for example if I am in NYC I want to display 3 options but if I'm in San Diego I want 5. My idea was to have a Linear Layout that has wrap_content as height with other linear layouts inside of it for each option. The problem is that I don't know how to modify(add/remove) the inside layouts to it or if there is a better way to implement this idea. Also the user is capable of selecting one of the options, they are clickable.

Here are some examples

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code what I have tried for adding a linear layout dynamically, it worked :). First load the parent layout in which you want to dynamically create the linear layouts. Then you have to decide the number of layouts to be displayed and pass it to the 'NumberOfLayouts' variable in the code it will dynamically create the linear layouts.

```
 /*Loading the Parent Layout*/
 LinearLayout ParentLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.ParentLayout);

    /*Dynamically creating your linear layouts*/
    for(int i=0; i<NumberOfLayouts; i++){
      LinearLayout linearLayout = new LinearLayout(getApplication());

        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setText("Sample Text");

        linearLayout.addView(textView);

        ParentLayout.addView(linearLayout);

        /*Adding listener for the individual layouts*/
        linearLayout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
              //Your code or method to be executed while clicking the dynamically created linear layout
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

This may be better accomplished with a [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html). It will allow you to generate a list of Views and control how many appear and their design. The RecyclerView can scroll so it can fit in whatever layout you have.

Answer (score 1):

```
        // first, find the container view by using findViewById;
    LinearLayout root = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.container);

    // then inflate the child view by using an inflater
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View childView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.childView, null);

    // finally, add the child view to the container
    root.addView(childView);
```